# Specific query for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query

I am creating a directory and have a custom post type called "listings".

I want to display a grid of "Most viewed" listings as well as "Highest rated" listings on my homepage and throughout the website.

I am really not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For most popular you can use something like https://github.com/williamsba/WordPress-Popular-Posts-with-Custom-Post-Type-Support/blob/master/wordpress-popular-posts.php

Actually there are several plugin and solutions it you check google, did you try it?

Comment: I was not aware of any plugins that can do this. Can you recommend any?

Comment: Check these https://github.com/williamsba/WordPress-Popular-Posts-with-Custom-Post-Type-Support/blob/master/wordpress-popular-posts.php , https://github.com/williamsba/WordPress-Popular-Posts-with-Custom-Post-Type-Support . I didn’t use any but that should work for you

Comment: I installed the plugin but it is very unclear on how to add a custom post type.  It seems they have updated the settings and you can no longer set the parameters.  Is there any code I can change to make it only get the post type 'listing' ?

Answer (score 0):

If using a plugin is a problem then try custom code, see solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142214/2975536